# line chart issue in dc.js when y value is 0

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

in dc.js line chart ,when all y value is zero corresponding to the x axis value line is not drawing. it just displying xaxis and y-axis without ticks.Is it possible to draw line on the x axis with corresponding y value as 0 with x-axis name(field name)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot. I suspect that the line is being drawn but it is under the X axis so you can't see it very well, as shown [in this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1656) (see faint, thin blue line above X axis).